# Error 1009 : Cannot access a property of method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, null, typeerror

I don't understand what is going on
This is my Main.as

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var pirkles:Circles = new Circles()

    public function Main() {

        gotoAndStop(1)

        playbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  playscreen)

    }

    public function playscreen(event:MouseEvent):void {

        gotoAndStop(2)

        addChild(pirkles)

    }
}

}
```

And this is my Circles.as

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Circles extends MovieClip{

    public function Circles():void {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, MOVE)
        this.y = 175
        this.x = 10
        }

    public function MOVE(event:KeyboardEvent):void {

        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {

            this.x = this.x+10

        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {  

            this.x = this.x-10

        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {

            this.y = this.y-10

        }
        else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {

            this.y = this.y+10

        }

    }

}

}
```

Now I get an error that says there is a problem at line 11 of my Circles.as and at line 8 of my Main.as. However, at those lines I don't understand what is causing the problem. I added a event listener at line 11, but when I take it out it works. Also, at line 8, I Just defined a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't access the stage in a class constructor.
So the line

```
 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, MOVE)
```

is causing the error.

If you need to access the stage, add a listener in the constructor for the ADDED_TO_STAGE event, and in the callback function you will be able to access the stage

So:

```
public function Circles():void {
        this.addEventListener (Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        this.y = 175
        this.x = 10
}

private function onAddedToStage (evt:Event):void {
                 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, MOVE)

}
```

Comment: Could you show me an example? I am fairly new to actionscript.

Comment: Also, is there anything wrong with my line 8 in my Main.as?